# Measuring Current In/Out of Resistors

Tags: electrical-engineering, circuits

[image]

The banana clips attach to a multi-meter out of view, the power supply wires are correctly in place, and the resistors are correctly in place. Would putting the red left-hand banana clip and its respective wire into the H15 tie node place the multi-meter in a correct--i.e. series and not parallel--position to measure total current out?

Comment: To measure current then the meter has to either be "in" the circuit or you need a shunt in the circuit then measure the voltage drop across that.

Comment: Thank you Solar Mike! Would placing the red left-hand banana clip and its respective wire into the H15 tie node place the multi-meter "'in' the circuit?"

Comment: do you have a circuit diagram? That would be far more instructive to look at then the breadboard.

Comment: No, I'm not going to trace the connections to infer the schematic.  It's your job to post one.  Then there are various mentions of "correct" without any spec of desired operation.  We do engineering here, not hand waving.  Closing as *unclear*.

Answer (score 1):

No. Placing the red lead into H15 would not allow you to measure the current, because the black lead of the multimeter would still be in I15.  H15 and I15 are connected together (at least on a standard breadboard), so the two leads of the multimeter are essentially connected together. That won't measure anything. As far as I understand the picture, you would have to do the following (in this order)

1) remove the black power supply lead from J 15

2) remove the black multi-meter lead from I 15

3) move the red multi-meter lead to H15

4) connect the black multi-meter lead to the power supply lead.

DISCLAIMER: these instructions are only as good as my understanding of the circuit.  Without a circuit diagram, I may have misunderstood. If you aren't 100% sure, ask for clarification first. In current mode, the impedance of the multimeter is very low, so if you connect in the wrong place you may overload the meter. Make sure you are using a fused multi-meter, and put it on a setting appropriate for the current you expect to measure.  Many multi-meters have different spots to plug in the leads, one for high current and one for low current.  Some cheaper meters may have unfused inputs.  Only use those if you are very sure about what you are doing.

If this doesn't make sense, then post a circuit diagram and we can elaborate on the answer.