# Not getting accurate readings from my multimeter

Tags: instrumentation

**EDITED THIS POST FOR THE PEOPLE WHO PROVIDED ME WITH GREAT FEEDBACK**

I have been building a few simple project circuits, mainly to analyze electronic theory.

The problem I'm having right now is that I'm using a cheap multi-meter from amazon that is giving me wild and inaccurate readings on DC current.

The case at hand is SIMPLE-CIRCUIT-A:

- 9V Battery(multimeter is only reading about 7.5 from across the terminals)
- 2x 200-ohm resistors in series, totaling for 400ohms
- 1 small piece of #22 wire
- 1 breadboard

[image: Circuit image]

If I listen to the mutimeters readings on the 9V battery as being only about 7.5V, then i should be pulling about 18.75mA at any point in the series circuit:

[![Circuit schematic and math][2]][2]

But this is what I'm actually getting:

[image: Inaccurate DC reading]

Now you could say, "Maybe the battery really is applying 9V across the circuit.", that conclusion would give us a DC of 22.5mA, yet im getting at best a reading of 24.5mA, that's a 9% error margin!!!

Could there be an issue with my multimeter? On top of that, I can never get stable readings from the leads, is that common in all multimeters? Usually when I apply the leads to a component to read DC, the numbers will bounce all over the place.

Comment: measure the resistors out of circuit, otherwise you get the circuit resistance as well.

Comment: I have been doing just that, resistance readings are accurate, plus I checked the color bands. I read something in my multimeter manual that says "Switch range to desired DCA range", which makes me think maybe I have been measuring alternating currents instead of D.C. How would I know on the multimeter if I have the right range, as in D.C vs AC?

Comment: are you in the same class with this guy? https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/17101/7461  In any case, show a circuit diagram and explain exactly how you are connecting your meter.  (Even cheap ones are pretty good these days)

Comment: If you are unclear on DC vs AC, keep learning.

Comment: @Harper I checked the multimeter settings. It's set to D.C.-current. And it doesn't work, it will either not read at al, go through a wide range, or give a highly inaccurate reading. The meter is completely going against the calculations I have made against ohms law.

Comment: @IamPyre well that could be a battery, or China Syndrome.  If you are actually serious about entering this field, it may be time for you to buy your Fluke.

Comment: given the quality level of your description I'm quite certain this is a case of operator error.

Comment: @agentp Yeah, real funny. Lol

Comment: ok, that is  much more to go on. I don't know I'd call 25% off "wild and inaccurate", but you should try to find another meter to compare against. The fluctuation is obviously a poor connection someplace or a bad meter.  Trying some different probe leads might be a good idea,

Comment: I ordered a Fluk-117 earlier tonight. Considering my other multimeter though, is it normal for a multimeter to unsteadily go through a wide range while you are applying the leads to the component? This multimeter only does it when it's set to detect current. Readings of voltage and resistance are steady.

Comment: check the voltage across the battery while the resistors are connected. There is an internal resistance in the battery that create a possibly significant difference.

Comment: note the meter reading is high already, so if the 7.5 is no-load that would put it further off

Comment: How about you try a different 9-V battery?  And how about cross-calibrating your meter against some reliable source, perhaps your 12V car battery (which may well be 11 to 15 V but will certainly be "stiff")

Comment: It wouldn't hurt for you to proof-read your own post so you'd see the link to schematic is busted.

Comment: your  _Circuit schematic and math_ image is missing

Comment: @MahendraGunawardena Yeah, SE told me I didn't have enough rank to post all three photos. I have to find another way to share it.

Comment: I see that you have 11 points so I think now you can post more than 2 images.